# Handling multiple levels of dynamic nesting attributes with RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit

Here is an example of the JSON I want to map. It contains 3 nested keys that are dynamic values (representing year, month and day).

```
{
  "data" : {
    "2013" : {
      "8" : {
        "1" : [
          {
            user : {
              name : "tom"
            }
          },
          {
            user : {
              name : "pat"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to map this kind of JSON inside an object that would have a single NSDictionary property with 3 levels, the 3rd level being a User object and all preceding levels being a NSDictionary?

RestKit documentation explains how to deal with a one level dynamic nesting attributes, not several levels.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you read that one ? https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md

Comment: Sure, and more precisely https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md#handling-dynamic-nesting-attributes. But as I said, it deals only with single level dynamic nesting attributes.

Comment: Did you try implementing it for multiple levels? What didn't work?

Comment: Don't know how to do it. Any recomendation?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way you'll get this to work is by using [nested attribute handling](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md#handling-dynamic-nesting-attributes) coupled with [dynamic mappings](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md#dynamic-object-mapping). You'll probably need to walk the hierarchy of the received JSON and create a mapping for each level in the dynamic mapping.

You may find it easier, because only the `User` object is truly mapped, to just use the underlying `AFNetworking` code to download the JSON and then map the `User` yourself (for which you could use a RestKit mapping operation).